# How to correctly initialize a Boolean as a variable for use as a "switch"

Tags: python, function

```
#Bounce bullet when it reaches corners.
def bullet_bounce(rect):
    bottom_corner = False
    if bottom_corner == False:
        rect.y +=5
        if rect.bottom == 400:
            bottom_corner = True
    if bottom_corner == True:
        rect.y -=5
        if rect.top == 0:
            bottom_corner = False
```

While working with pygame to create Pong I want to make a rectangle bounce every time it reaches the corner of the screen. I came up with this code and it works as intented when I initialize `bottom_corner` outside the game loop and then run the rest of the code inside the loop. But since it would look much cleaner I want to implement this code inside as a function. The problem is since the function is called inside the loop `bottom_corner` is initialized as False every time the loop runs which leads to only the first half of the code being iterated. Do you have any recommendations on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe you should define as `def bullet_bounce(rect, bottom_corner):` to get this value as parameter. But it would need also to use `return bottom_corner` and run as `bottom_corner = bullet_bounce(rect, bottom_corner)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define variable outside function and send to function as parameter and get it back with `return`

```
def bullet_bounce(rect, bottom_corner):
    if not bottom_corner:
        rect.y +=5
        if rect.bottom == 400:
            bottom_corner = True
    else:
        rect.y -=5
        if rect.top == 0:
            bottom_corner = False

    return bottom_corner

# --- start program ---

bottom_corner = False

# --- some loop ---

while True:

    bottom_corner = bullet_bounce(rect, bottom_corner)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question. But I recommend you avoid making equality comparisons between boolean values(True, False) and boolean variables. Instead of saying `if bottom_corner == True` use `if bottom_corner:` and `else:`

And to switch boolean variables you can use the `not` operator

```
#Bounce bullet when it reaches corners.
def bullet_bounce(rect):
    if bottom_corner: rec.y -=5 
    else rec.y += 5
    if (rec.bottom == 400) or (rect.top == 0): 
        # switch it based on previous value
        bottom_corner = not bottom_corner
```